# Can't start thin server from bash script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, thin

I'm trying to start my Rails app with thin from the shell script. If I run the commands manually, everything works fine, but if I run the script, it just won't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/my/project_1
thin -e production -p 3000 --daemonize -s 10 start
cd /path/to/my/project_2
thin -e production -p 3010 --daemonize -s 10 start
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: So if you copy and paste that text into a terminal, it works, but if you run the shell script, it doesn’t work? I assume you have execute permission on the script. Can you give any more information?

Comment: @yellowantphil - that's it! - execution permissions - was missin ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was solved in the comments, but for posterity’s sake:

Make sure you have execute permission on the script. `chmod 755 my_awesome_script` ought to do it.