# Starting Django server from bash script doesn't persist

Tags: bash

So this seems to be a relatively common occurrence (lots of similar questions have been asked like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759882/cant-start-thin-server-from-bash-script) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464997/bash-terminal-closes-after-running-a-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060495/cant-start-server-in-openshift)) with some variations. I have execute permissions for the script and have tried all the solutions mentioned in those questions but it's still not working. When I try to run the following command to start my Django server, the bash script opens and closes. How do I get it to persist after starting the server?

startserver.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 manage.py runserver 7888
```

So the command runs when I type it directly into cmd (in that directory), but when I try to run the bash file it just flashes and disappears. I have tried running it as

```
.\startserver.sh
. startserver.sh
sh startserver.sh
start startserver.sh
```

but each does the same. Ideally I would like to have it such that you can double click on the server.sh file and it runs persistently. Anyone have any ideas why this is the case? I feel like it's something very small I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [nohup](/questions/tagged/nohup) to your script.

Change

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 manage.py runserver 7888
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
START=`pwd`
nohup python3 manage.py runserver 7888 >"${START}/startserver.LOG" 2>"${START}/startserver.ERR"
```

You **don't** want to rely on the longevity or continued existence of [nohup.out](/questions/tagged/nohup.out) because that default destination can be easily clobberred by other programs.